# If I can have the ActionEvent of Menu without Action

Tags: java, javafx, menu, fxml, actionevent

I work on a project in JavaFX and I need to get the ActionEvent of a menu when the program starts.I actually did some research on it but I couldn't find any reasonable answer.Is there any way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: You can get the event handler for the `onAction` event; You can also create a `ActionEvent` instance yourself. Although writing "access the functionality of the edit menu item" in code will be less elegant than something like this `editMenu.setOnAction(evt -> edit()); ... /*access "event"*/ edit();`

Comment: I mean getting the actionevent without clicking the menu.How can I create an instance of the actionevent in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Post some code. Do you use the `ActionEvent` in the handler?